# Facebook Android SDK records "Unknown" App Version for "App Installs" events

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am integrating with the Facebook Android SDK so that I can correlate app installs with the Facebook Ads that we are running.

I've followed [the instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads#overview) carefully and I've confirmed that my events are getting logged to Facebook.  I've also used JD-GUI to confirm that obfuscation isn't happening on the Facebook classes.

[image: mixed_events]

The weird thing is that all my "App Installs" events show an "App Version" of "Unknown" (this screenshot shows me filtering for "App Installs" events):

[image: fb_analytics_events]

This might be benign (I'm still investigating), but does anybody know the cause?  Thanks!

Comment: This is a previously reported issue, you can track it at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/741529029271367/

Comment: Are you sure?  I searched and was unable to find it in the bug database...

Comment: Yeah see the one I linked in my comment above: "Sometimes, I see 'App Installs' event with 'Unknown' for both 'Client' and 'App Version' on 'Most Recently logged events' . Why is it showing 'Unknown' ?"

Comment: Weird, that link doesn't open the issue for me, and I can't find it by searching either.  If I open an existing bug and alter the ID in the URL to match yours, it just takes me back to the trending bugs page.  :-/

Comment: You can file another bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs, sorry I hadn't noticed that issue isn't generally viewable.